# Appending to list not updating on pull to refresh

Tags: model-view-controller, sencha-touch-2, pull-to-refresh

I am still new to ST so I am probably doing several things wrong here but I can't figure out where the problems are.

**Problem 1**
when I use the pull to refresh plug-in, I get double the data instead of it just refreshing the data. I have seen to use a propertyId and so I did to no avail. This should be simple so probably something silly I'm doing wrong.

**Problem 2**
I am trying to figure out the most efficient way to use the MVC architecture and I have read through the documentation and many examples. So, I don't know if I am just not understanding clearly or need a better example. I am trying to create a simple app for now with a list that I can tap on an item and get a detailed view of that item. I will later evolve it into a more robust monster but for now I am trying to understand the basics. I finally got my close button to close the detail view when I click a list item but then I can no longer get a detail view when tapping another item. I have read that this is due to 'autoDestroy: off' not being present but I tried that, also with no luck. I want to be able to create certain buttons like 'close' that I can put in multiple views and just have to have the logic in the controllers.

**Main View**

```
Ext.define('SenchaFirstApp.view.DistributorView', {
     //      extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
     extend: 'Ext.Container',
       requires: ['SenchaFirstApp.store.DistributorStore', 'Ext.dataview.List', 'Ext.Toolbar', 'Ext.form.Panel'],
       model: 'SenchaFirstApp.model.Distributors',
       alias: 'widget.mainlist',
       xtype: 'mainlist',
       config:
       {
           layout: 'fit',
           border: 5,
           title: 'Distributors',
           html: 'My datalist',
           autoDestroy: false,
           items:[{

               xtype: 'toolbar',
               docked: 'top',
               title: 'Distributor List',
               height: 40,
               centered: true,
               items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Close',
                    width: 100,
                    height: 20, 
                    name: 'close',
            //      iconCls: 'delete',
                }]
               },
           {
           autoLoad: true,
           html: ['<div class="distr"><table><tr><th>Type</th><th>Distributor</th><th>Site</th><th>Status</th><th>Active</th><th>Assigned</th><th>State                             </th><th>Schedule</th><th>Finished</th></tr></table></div>'],
           itemTpl: [ '<div class="distr"><table><tr><td>{t}</td><td>{distr}</td><td colspan="2">{site}</td><td>{status}</td>                                                       <td>{active}</td><td>{assigned}</td> <td>{state}</td><td>{schedule}</td><td>{finished}</td></tr></table></div>' ],
           xtype: 'list',
           store: 'DistrID', 
            plugins: [
    {
        xclass: 'Ext.plugin.PullRefresh',
        pullRefreshText: 'Pull down to refresh Distributor List'
    }],
           ui: 'showDetails',
           id: 'mainlist',
           autoDestroy: false,
           }          
        ]
       },          
     });
```

**Detailed View**

```
Ext.define('SenchaFirstApp.view.DetailView',{
      extend: 'Ext.Panel',
      requires: ['Ext.Toolbar'],
      model: 'SenchaFirstApp.model.Distributors',
      alias: 'widget.detailview',
      xtype: 'detailview',
      name: 'detail',


    config:{
         html: 'This will contain detailed information',
          xtype: 'panel',
    //    fullscreen: false,
          centered: true,
          modal: false,
          scrollable: true,
          width: 300,
          height: 200,
      },
       });
```

**Store**

```
Ext.define('SenchaFirstApp.store.DistributorStore', {
                        extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
                        requires: ['SenchaFirstApp.model.Distributors'],

                        config: {
                        //  xtype: 'distrlist',
                            storeId: 'DistrID',
                        model: 'SenchaFirstApp.model.Distributors',
                        autoLoad: true,
                        proxy: {
                            type: 'jsonp',
                            url:'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/hobbitin5/uploads&num=4',
                            reader: {
                                type: 'json',
                                rootProperty: 'responseData.feed.entries'
                            }
                        }
                            }
```

**Controller to get detailed view**

```
 Ext.define('SenchaFirstApp.controller.DistributorsController',{
       extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
       config: 
       {
           refs: 
           {
               mainlist: '#mainlist',
           },
           control: 
           {
               mainlist: {
                   itemtap: 'dispDetail'
               },
           },

       //when item is tapped
         listeners: {
                itemtap: function(list, index, items, record)
               {
                   console.log('An item was tapped and the listener heard it');
               }
           }
        },
        dispDetail: function(view, record) {
                console.log('Item was tapped on the Data View');
                var oldView = this.getMainlist();       
                var curRecord = oldView.getStore(record);
                var newView = Ext.create('SenchaFirstApp.view.DetailView');
                console.log(curRecord);
                curRecord += 'other stuff';
                newView.setHtml(curRecord);
                newView.add(
        {
         xtype:  'toolbar',
         docked: 'top',
         title: 'Details',
         height: 40,
         items: [
        {
          xtype: 'button',
          text: 'Close',
          width: 100,
          height: 20,   
          name: 'close',
        }]

        }
      )
                oldView.add(newView);
            //  Ext.Viewport.add(newView)
            //  Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(newView)
        }

       });
```

**Controller for buttons (just close for now)**

```
Ext.define('SenchaFirstApp.controller.NavController', {
       extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
       config: 
       {
            refs: 
            {
                 mainlist: 'mainlist',
                 main: '#mainlist',
                closeBtn: 'button[name=close]',
                detaillist: {
                    selector: 'panel panel[name=detail] deetaillist',
                    xtype: 'detailview',
                }
            }, 
            control:
            {
                closeBtn: {
                    tap: 'closeView',
                },

                mainlist: {
                    tap: 'closeView',
                },
                detaillist: {
                    tap: 'closeView',
                }
            }
       },

       closeView: function(){

            var newView = this.getMainlist();
        //  var child = Ext.Viewport.getActiveItem();
            var child = this.getDetaillist();
            var instance = Ext.getCmp('mainlist');
            var activeIndex = instance.indexOf(instance.getActiveItem());
            var curIndex = activeIndex+1;
            var closeView = this.getDetaillist();
            console.log('Close btn clicked' + ' child: ' + this.child +  ' activeIndex: ' + activeIndex);
          // Ext.Viewport.destroy(closeView); //(child);
          newView.remove(child);
          newView.destroy();
          Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('SenchaFirstApp.view.DistributorView'));
`          }


})`;
```

**Model**

```
Ext.define('SenchaFirstApp.model.Distributors', {
       extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
       config: {
           idProperty: 'DistrID',
             fields: [
                {name: 'DistrID'},
                {name: 't', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'distr', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'group', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'site', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'status', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'active', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'assigned', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'state', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'schedule', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'finished', type: 'string'},
                //{mapping: 't',
                // name: 'DistrID'}
                ],
       }
       });
```

I understand that is a lot but any help is appreciated...even a nudge in the right direction. Thanks in advance! Also, I'm sure there is stuff in there that doesn't need to be as I've had trouble locating good examples for what I am trying to accomplish so I have pieces here and there from different examples that I've tried to get to play nice together :(

Comment: Can you add your store definition?  It currently has the code for SenchaFirstApp.view.DistributorView

Comment: @Dave Barker, I apologize. I thought I had it but added my view again in place of the store. It's there now, thanks for your response. The url is one I just found somewhere to have something in my list (null data). I'm working on building a file with actual data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the refresh issue by changing the idProperty to 'id' and put that in my model field list. I'm still not sure why the 'DistrID wasn't working but I had an 'id' field in my script that held the server response that I didn't know about as I didn't write that part. So, I would have to guess that is why it wasn't working.

I had read that 'autoDestroy: false' is what was needed to allow clicking a second time but that was wrong. When I took that property out it allowed me to continue to open and close details of list items.

Now I just have to work on passing id's of list items clicked to get a detailed view of that particular item. If anyone can help with that it would be great or I will post a new question. Thanks!

I figured out how to get the list item id in case it can help anyone...
Iny my DistributorController I simply get the store and the record id

```
var store = Ext.getStore('NodeStore');
            var id = record.get('id');
```

Then set the params and load the store

```
store.getProxy().setExtraParams({id: id});
            store.load();
```

I did also find that you can't reference your store through the controller with refs. Instead get the store as I did above with var store = Ext.getStore('StoreName');
This is all pretty simple stuff but I'm still very knew so maybe it can help out another n00b